# Diffrent typeid between platforms

Tags: c++, linux, windows, clang, typeid

I don't understand why this programs produces differents outputs between Linux and Windows using the same compiler. In Windows it outputs **float** and in Linux it outputs **f**.

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
        std::cout << typeid(float).name() << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: The name is not guaranteed to be anything in particular, it can differ between compilers and possibly even between different executions of the same program.

Comment: did you read [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name)?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: I'm not sure about that, unless the implementation specifically mentions that as a possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator returns the name from the [`std::type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info), which is described as

> The class type_info holds **implementation-specific information** about a type, including the name of the type and means to compare two types for equality or collating order. This is the class returned by the typeid operator.

So it is implementation-specific how they choose to name the types. This is reinforced again in [`std::type_info::name`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name)

> Returns an **implementation defined null-terminated character string containing the name of the type**. No guarantees are given; in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and change between invocations of the same program.

Answer (score 2):

From [[expr.typeid]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.typeid#1):

> The result of a `typeid` expression is an lvalue of static type `const std​::​type_­info` and dynamic type `const std​::​type_­info` or `const`
> *name* **where *name* is an implementation-defined class** publicly
> derived from std​::​type_­info which preserves the behavior described
> in [type.info]. [...]

the *name* is implementation-defined.

[[type.info]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/type.info#1) specifically mentions that [**emphasis** mine]:

> The class `type_­info` describes type information **generated by the
> implementation**. Objects of this class effectively store a pointer to
> a name for the type, and an encoded value suitable for comparing two
> types for equality or collating order. **The names, encoding rule, and
> collating sequence for types are all unspecified and may differ
> between programs**.

the name for the type pointed to is unspecified and may vary not only between implementations but even between programs (from the same implementation).

Answer (score 2):

There is cure for that. [boost has demangling](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/demangle.html) functionality.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <typeinfo>


int main()
{
    auto name = typeid(float).name();
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::core::demangle(name) << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Simple [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cb3cbK)

More complex [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8r3aGG)